# How can I link my Domain that ive purchased on NameCheap to my React Project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, namecheap

Ive been trying to deploy my react app with my Domain that i bought on NameCheap.

Couldnt find any answer (maybe, I am searching with a wrong keyward).

Do I use Node.JS to connect my Domain or is it possible to use the domain just with React?

Comment: You need web hosting, for example if it's a simple project you can consider github pages (which is free and your site is static)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing **Domain names** and **Hosting**.

Your app (React or React + Node or any other framework) needs to be **hosted** on a server (which can be a 'cloud' server or VPS - virtual private server). Well-known hosting services include Amazon (AWS), Heroku, Now (Zeit), DigitalOcean, etc.

Regardless of the hosting service, you will usually end up with a numeric IP address that points to your deployed application.

**Domain name** hosting is the other 'half'. When you buy a domain, you still have to set it up, i.e. you have to define the **DNS** (domain name service) entries for that domain, be it for serving a web site or app, a mail exchange, etc.
Your Domain name provider usually has an interface that allows you to edit DNS entries for any domain you purchased with them. This is where you will make the connection between your Domain name and your hosted app.
A typical top-level entry, known as an 'A' entry will be:

`mydomain.com A 91.223.9.9`

meaning route requests to `mydomain.com` to IP address `91.223.9.9` (the IP address you will have retrieved from your application hosting service).

Comment: Ahhhh thank you! I thought I had to setup things on the each side. This is a totally other question. What if someone hijack ip address and put it in ur DNS? For example, somehow someone found out of my React server ip address and that someone has connected his DNS to my ip address?

Comment: It is possible that his/her domain would then point to your app, although there are configurations to avoid that. Usually, hosting lets you manage virtual hosts, which let you connect specific domain name requests to a specific document tree (i.e. an application deployment). Unmanaged domain requests can be routed to a default page, an error page, etc. This is usually done at the web server level (apache/nginx) or through UIs such as cPanel, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If your project is not requiring node.js running in background, it is absolutely possible to host it with any hosting provider, including but not limited to Namecheap. If you purchased a hosting from them (or any other hosting provider) and ***successfully*** build your application (i.e. it works for you locally), just upload the contents of /build folder to your hosting server.

If your hosting provider is using cPanel (Namecheap does), this usually means that you should upload it to ~/public_html/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME.

If your application ***does*** require node.js, there are few hosting companies that offer this as well. I am not sure I'll be able to make any advertisements here, so please ask around. [Webhostingtalk](https://webhostingtalk.com) is a good place to start.